# Why strcpy doesn't work but direct assign works?

Tags: c, strcpy, dynamic-tables

In the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    char** tab;
    int n;
}slist;

void print(slist* p);
void add(slist* p, const char* s);
void add(slist* p, const char* s)
{
    if(p->n==0)
    {
        p->tab=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char**));
    }
    strcpy(p->tab[p->n],s);
    p->n=p->n+1;
}
void print(slist* p)
{
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i=0;i<p->n;i++)
        printf(" %s",p->tab[i]);
    printf(" ]");
}
int main()
{
    char s1[25] = "Picsou";
    char s2[25] = "Flairsou";
    slist* p = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
    p->n=0;
    p->tab=NULL;
    add(p,s1);
    add(p,s2);
    print(p);
    return 0;
}
```

the function `add()` doesn't work, but if I change it to:

```c
void add(slist* p, const char* s)
{
    if(p->n==0)
    {
        p->tab=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char**));
    }
    p->tab[p->n]=s;
    p->n=p->n+1;
}
```

it seems to work perfectly well.  In the first case the output is only `" ["`;
in the second case it is what is should be: `" [ Picsou Flairsou ] "`.
I cannot understand why.
I also tried this :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
    char** tab;
    int n;
}slist;

void print(slist* p);
void add(slist* p, const char* s);

void print(slist* p)
{
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i=0;i<p->n;i++)
        printf(" %s",p->tab[i]);
    printf(" ]");
}
void add(slist* p, const char* s)
{
    slist* tmp = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
    tmp->tab=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(p->n+1));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<p->n;i++)
         tmp->tab[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tmp->tab[p->n],s);
    tmp->n=p->n+1;
    p = tmp;
}
int main()
{
    char* s1 = "Picsou";
    char* s2 = "Flairsou";
    slist* p = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
    p->n=0;
    p->tab=NULL;
    add(p,s1);
    add(p,s2);
    print(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You allocate space for the collection of pointers, but never allocate anything for those pointers to point to.

Comment: I edited the post, I tried what you said, but it still doesn't work, i don't know what to do...
But thank you for your answer ^^

Comment: @Maxime Fleury: You allocate memory for 1 char and then attempt to copy the entire string into that memory. No wonder it doesn't work. And why are you casting the result of `malloc`?

Comment: `slist* tmp = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));`? You already allocated this in `main()`.  You also don't need all those casts for `malloc()`.

Comment: Also, why are you suddenly allocating a new list in `add`? You new version makes modifications to that new list and then throws it away. What is the point of that?

Comment: I'm learning c and i'm trying to do a list, in order to do that, i tried to do that : 
`p->tab[p->n+1]=malloc(sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(p->tab[p->n],s);
    p->n=p->n+1;
`

Comment: @MaximeFleury Stop and go back to the text books. Try something smaller and get that going first. You aren't a 1 star programmer yet but you are trying to write 2 star code (not having a go, just counting the `*`s in your pointer code).

Comment: @MaximeFleury Why not try writing it all in `main()` first. Make sure you get that working first. I feel like your juggling too much at once. Get pointers down first, then start abstracting your code more.

Comment: I cannot not do it that's a TP ... I'm a student, I'm just not good with pointers, I can code games, and graphical programs, but not in C or C++...
I need to get better, and by doing in advence TPs I usaly get top grades but this time with thoses pointers my mind seg' fault...

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via one blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the result.  The type of the result is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `p->tab=malloc(sizeof(char**));` is allocating (on 32 bit architectures) 4 bytes.  You really want to allocate `strlen(s)+1` bytes  otherwise, if `s` is more than 3 bytes long, the call to `strcpy()` will overrun the receiving buffer, which is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `p->tab=malloc(strlen(s));`

Comment: the field `p->tab` is defined as a point to a list of pointers.  the `add()` function only (ever) allocates room on the list of pointers for a single pointer (it should on each execution of the `add()` function use 'realloc()` to increase the size of that list of pointers by `p->n +1`  Then allocate the memory needed for the string `s` and assign that resulting pointer to `p->tab[n]`  Then finally call `strcpy()` with the destination being: `p->tab[n]` and the source being: `s`

Answer (score 2):

Lots of errors here, which is common with people who are new to dealing with pointers.  Where to begin...  I'll just go in the order things appear in code.

1. **This is not a "list".**

   It's an array... sort of.  If you say "list" to a C programmer, they will think you mean a linked-list.
2. **Incorrect allocation of array.**

   > ```
   > if(p->n==0)
   > {
   >     p->tab=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char**));
   > }
   > ```

   Here you have allocated enough to store a single pointer.  The second time you call `add`, you're going to access memory off the end.  You have also incorrectly cast the result (in C, you don't cast the return value from `malloc`).  Additionally, you have given confusing information to the reader, because you intend to allocate an array that will hold elements of type `char*`, *NOT* `char**`.

   You must either allow the array to expand dynamically when required (not appropriate for your abilities right now - maybe try that in a few days), or set a maximum size.  Let's do that.

   ```
   const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
   if( p->n==0 )
   {
       p->tab = malloc( MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char*) );
   }
   else if( p->n == MAX_SIZE )
   {
       printf( "Maximum size exceeded!\n" );
       return;
   }
   ```

   You could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` if you like.  It will zero-initialise the block after allocating it: `calloc( MAX_SIZE, sizeof(char*) )`
3. **Copying to an uninitialized pointer.**

   > ```
   > strcpy(p->tab[p->n],s);
   > ```

   You allocated memory for `tab`, but you did not allocate memory that is pointed to by its elements, and here you have undefined behaviour (most likely resulting in a segmentation fault, but could do anything).

   Make sure you have a valid pointer, and the location it points has enough storage reserved for the data you are copying into it:

   ```
   p->tab[p->n] = malloc( strlen(s) + 1 );
   strcpy( p->tab[p->n], s );
   ```
4. **Storing potentially invalid pointer.**

   Your alternative that "works perfectly well" uses:

   > ```
   > p->tab[p->n]=s;
   > ```

   However, the only reason this works is because those pointers remain valid for the whole time that you use the "list" (but actually the program does not "work" because of reasons I highlighted in number 2.

   Sometimes we desire this behaviour in a program, and design our data structures to index pointers that they do not own.  But more often, and especially for a beginner, you are better off copying the data (instead of simply copying the pointer).  And so you'll instead use the approach I've suggested in number 3 above.
5. **No comment!!**

   There are so many things wrong with the following code, that I'm not going to pull it apart or explain them.

   > ```
   > void add(slist* p, const char* s)
   > {
   >     slist* tmp = (slist*)malloc(sizeof(slist));
   >     tmp->tab=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(p->n+1));
   >     int i;
   >     for(i=0;i<p->n;i++)
   >          tmp->tab[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   >     strcpy(tmp->tab[p->n],s);
   >     tmp->n=p->n+1;
   >     p = tmp;
   > }
   > ```

   However, it appears like you were attempting to do something similar to `realloc`.  This is the option I mentioned in number 2 that I said you're maybe not ready for.  But read up on it anyway: [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

Comment: Nice answer :) +1 from me.

Comment: this answer is good, however; Suggest also checking that each call to a heap allocation function (malloc, calloc, realloc) be immediately followed by a check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  And the posted code fails to pass each of the allocated memory pointers to `free()` before exiting.  While the OS will probably cleanup, that should never be depended upon

Comment: Yeah thanks for that.  I intentionally left out the checks for clarity, but since I was listing points, I should have taken the time to cover that.